# Save dynamically created views

Tags: android, android-view, savestate

I'm working on activity where user can add more input fields( 2 spinners and 1 edit text) on button click. This mechanism works fine until activity is recreated (rotation etc). All dynamically added views are lost.I'm looking for the the baest way to save state of views. Unfortunately I can not store list of views in onSaveInstanceState() method also I can not lock screen orientation. What can be a solution to resolve this problem?
Here is activity java code

public class ReportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ImageButton addNew;
private LinearLayout mLayout;
private int categorySpinnerId =1001; //IDs of categorySpinner
private int currencySpinnerId =2001; //IDs of currencySpinner
private int editTextValueId =3001;   //Ids of editText


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.report_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.report_item_layout);
    mLayout.addView(createNewCategorySpinner());
    mLayout.addView(createNewEditText());
    mLayout.addView(createNewCurrencySpinner());

    addNew = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_new);



    addNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mLayout.addView(createNewCategorySpinner());
            mLayout.addView(createNewEditText());
            mLayout.addView(createNewCurrencySpinner());
        }
    });
}

//Generates operation category spinner
private Spinner createNewCurrencySpinner() {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    spinner.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> currencySpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.report_activity_currency_spinner,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    currencySpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(currencySpinnerAdapter);
    spinner.setId(currencySpinnerId);
    spinner.setSaveEnabled(true);
    Log.d("ID", spinner.getId() + "");
    currencySpinnerId++;
    return spinner;
}

//Generates currency type spinner

private Spinner createNewCategorySpinner() {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    spinner.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> categorySpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.report_activity_category_spinner,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    categorySpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(categorySpinnerAdapter);
    spinner.setId(categorySpinnerId);
    spinner.setSaveEnabled(true);
    Log.d("ID", spinner.getId() + "");
    categorySpinnerId++;
    return spinner;
}

//Generates operation input value edit text

private EditText createNewEditText() {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    editText.setHint("Value");
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    editText.setId(editTextValueId);
    editText.setSaveEnabled(true);
    Log.d("ID", editText.getId() + "");
    editTextValueId++;
    return editText;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store enough information in your saved instance state `Bundle` to be able to recreate and repopulate the dynamically-created views in the new activity instance.